# STEAMCMD: Assertion Failed: Failed to write app state file

Tags: linux, steam

I'm setting up a gmod server on Linux but I get an error saying it failed to write app state. I read somewhere it was something to do with permission but I'm not sure how to fix it.  What is causing this error and how can it be fixed?

```
Steam>force_install_dir /home/steam/gmod

Steam>app_update 4020
/home/buildbot/buildslave/steam_rel_client_linux/build/src/clientdll/applicationmanager.cpp (937) : Assertion Failed: Failed to write app state file /home/steam/gmod/b880344e252db2ff689623b22f39bb22fdbd1e01/appmanifest_4020.acf
/home/buildbot/buildslave/steam_rel_client_linux/build/src/clientdll/applicationmanager.cpp (937) : Assertion Failed: Failed to write app state file /home/steam/gmod/b880344e252db2ff689623b22f39bb22fdbd1e01/appmanifest_4020.acf
 Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
Error! App '4020' state is 0x1 after update job.
```

Comment: Which user are you trying to install steam under? buildbot?

Comment: I created a user called gmod, im installing it under that

Comment: You are installing it to directory `/home/steam` which usually belongs to user steam. gmod's directory would be `/home/gmod`

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved with root account. Launched steamcmd with root and then updated the app. No errors occurred. I hope could help someone.